# Select all categories with topic and post count

Tags: mysql

I have categories with `id`, topics with `id` and `category`, and posts with `id` and `topic`. I'd like to list categories along with the number of topics belonging to each category as well as number of posts belonging to topics belonging to those categories.

what I'm using thus far to gather categories and their respective topic counts

```
select c.*, count(t.id) topics
    from categories c
    join topics t
        on t.category=c.id
    group by c.id
```

I've tried the following, but it just gives me the same post and topic count

```
select c.*, count(t.id) topics, count(p.id) posts
    from categories c
    join topics t
        on t.category=c.id
    join posts p
        on p.topic=t.id
    group by c.id
```

trying `left join` doesn't seem to make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT t.id)` to only count the unique topic ids per category.

```
select c.*, count(DISTINCT t.id) topics, count(p.id) posts
from categories c
join topics t
    on t.category=c.id
join posts p
    on p.topic=t.id
group by c.id
```

Alternatively, you can use subqueries:

```
select c.*, 
   count(t.id) topics, 
   (   select count(p.id) 
       from posts p 
       where p.topic = t.id
   ) posts
from categories c
join topics t
    on t.category=c.id
group by c.id
```

or even

```
select c.*, 

   (  select count(t.id) 
      from topics t 
      where t.category = c.id) topics,

   (  select count(p.id) 
      from topics t 
      join posts p 
          on p.topic = t.id
      where t.category = c.id) posts
from categories c
```

In this particular case `count(distinct)` is obviously the easiest, but in other cases, subqueries can give you more possibilities.

Comment: Thanks! But if I knew you were going to say that, I wouldn't have added the whole chapter on subqueries. ;-)